# Expression donner beaucoup pour peu

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Est-ce qu'il existe une expression qui signifierait "donner beaucoup en échange de peu", ou pour essayer d'être un peu plus précis, "faire des concessions importantes en échange de petits gains qui ne valent pas le coup" ?

L'expression "victoire à la Pyrrhus" porte un peu la même idée, mais ne me paraît pas non plus être exactement appropriée...

Comment: Se faire avoir ?

Comment: Est-ce que c'est plutôt porté vers l'idée de quelqu'un de généreux, ou de quelque chose qu'il faudrait éviter de faire ?

Comment: Quelque chose qu'il faut éviter de faire, un mauvais deal. Il n'y a cependant pas la notion de se faire avoir, le contexte c'est plutôt "il ne va pas faire cet échange parce que ce serait donner 1000 en échange de 100". Idem pour "le jeu n'en vaut pas la chandelle", il y a la notion de pari, de risque, alors que dans ma situation, les résultats sont connus.

Answer (score 3):

[Cette question sur ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104278/idiom-request-putting-too-much-effort-but-the-return-is-so-low-that-it-was-not) demande à peu près la même chose en anglais (“Idiom request: Putting too much effort, but the return is so low that it was not worth the effort”) et une des réponses est, justement, la traduction de "victoire à la Pyrrhus", que vous mentionnez, mais il y en a aussi une en forme de la traduction littéralle de l’expression française:

[**Le jeu n'en vaut pas la chandelle**](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/le-jeu-n-en-vaut-pas-la-chandelle.php) qui d’apres *expressio.fr* veut dire :

> Cela n'en vaut pas la peine.
>    Cela ne justifie pas les frais envisagés
>   ou les problèmes qui vont en découler.
>    Origine Cette expression, sous
>   une forme très approchante, date du XVIe siècle.
>
> Il ne faut pas oublier qu'à cette époque la fée électricité n'existait
>   pas encore et que ceux qui s'adonnaient aux jeux (cartes, dés...),
>   particulièrement ceux donnant lieu à des enjeux, devaient s'éclairer à
>   la chandelle, considérée comme un objet de luxe.
>    Il était d'ailleurs
>   d'usage, dans les endroits modestes, que les participants laissent
>   quelque argent en partant pour dédommager du coût de cet éclairage.
>    Et
>   lorsque les gains étaient faibles, ils ne couvraient même pas le prix
>   de la chandelle.

Answer (score 0):

Je suggère : faire une mauvaise affaire.